# Is the array order of requested products from itunes store always same ? IAP

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, request, in-app-purchase

I request the products from the itunes store with these codes :

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
_productsRequest = nil;

NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
    NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
          skProduct.productIdentifier,
          skProduct.localizedTitle,
          skProduct.price.floatValue);
}

_completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
_completionHandler = nil;
```

}

```
- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {

_completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

_productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
_productsRequest.delegate = self;
[_productsRequest start];
```

}

When someone press buy button I use this code

```
[[IAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
                        if (success)
                        {
                            SKProduct *product = _products[NUMBER];
                            [[IAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
                        }
                    }];
```

I know the order of my products and I put their number where I wrote "NUMBER" above. I need to know if this product request's returning array is always in the same order. 
Thank you all ...